# Getting `ScriptException` when using Kotlin `ScriptEngine` in tests run from Maven

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, scriptengine

In a Maven project I have tests that are using the Kotlin `ScriptEngine` (just calling `scriptEngine.eval(script)`). When I run the tests from IntelliJ they all pass, but during runs of `mvn test`, I am getting the following error:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot access script base class 'kotlin.script.experimental.jsr223.KotlinJsr223DefaultScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access script provided property class 'kotlin.script.experimental.jvmhost.jsr223.KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineImpl'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access script provided property class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.AggregatedReplStageState'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I have these three classes in the classpath via appropriate Maven dependencies. (I actually added a call to `System.out.println(KotlinJsr223DefaultScript.class.getName())` in the failing tests to make sure it's the case.) Here's the relevant fragment of the dependency tree:

```
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm-host:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:jar:1.0.20181211:runtime
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-js:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-util-klib:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-util-io:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl:jar:1.3.72:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler:jar:1.3.72:runtime
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:jar:1.3.72:runtime
```

I saw people on the Internet run into similar issues, but their solution was to make sure the classes are available on the classpath, which I already have.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I have the same issue with Kotlin 1.4.10 as well as 1.4.21. I tried to explicitly add all dependencies with test scope but it didn't help.

Comment: @hanslovsky I finally was able to make it work. I ended up using these dependencies in the test scope: `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jsr223-embeddable:1.3.72`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.72`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-util:1.3.72`. I recall there's some issue with running it unless you call `org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.environment.UtilKt.setIdeaIoUseFallback()` before getting an instance of the script engine from `KotlinJsr223JvmLocalScriptEngineFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for following up with a solution that works for you (you can answer and accept your own answer). Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I am also working with version `1.4.21`, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: FYI, I started a topic on the Kotlin forum: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/maven-tests-with-scriptengine-run-in-intellij-but-fail-on-command-line/20369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the unit tests to work on the command line. The issue was the surefire plugin that would use a manifest-only jar that would contain the classpath. For some reason, the order in which the jars were listed in that manifest-only jar caused the issues that OP describes above. I was able to fix this issue by setting `surefire.useManifestOnlyJar=false`, either in `pom.xml`

```xml
<properties>
    <surefire.useManifestOnlyJar>false</surefire.useManifestOnlyJar>
</properties>
```

or as command line argument for Maven:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.useManifestOnlyJar=false test
```

For more details on that property, see

```
mvn surefire:help -Ddetail=true
```

This resolves the problem for me.

There is also documentation on class loading with surefire: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html